# Properties of a linear operator given an inequality

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a Banach** space and let $X'$ be its dual. Let $x_0 \in X$ and assume that there is $L \in X'$ such that for every $x \in X$ $$\frac{1}{2}\|x_0\|_X^2 - L(x_0) \le \frac{1}{2}\|x\|_X^2 - L(x).$$
I want to prove that $L(x_0) = \|x_0\|_X^2$ and furthermore that $\|L\|_{X'} = \|x_0\|_X$.

**I am not sure that we really need the space to be Banach (normed should be enough), but it is also true that performing only algebraic operations on the above inequality I could not prove anything.. So even if it is irrelevant for the formulation of the problem it is not impossible that we really need the space to be Banach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For $\lVert\xi\rVert_X = 1$, on the line through $0$ and $\xi$, the minimal value of

$$h_\xi(t) = \frac{\lVert t\xi\rVert_X^2}{2} - L(t\xi) = \frac{1}{2}t^2 - t\cdot L(\xi)$$

is $-\frac{1}{2}L(\xi)^2$, attained at $t = L(\xi)$. Thus if

$$\frac{\lVert x_0\rVert_X^2}{2} - L(x_0) \leqslant \frac{\lVert x\rVert_X^2}{2} - L(x)\tag{1}$$

for all $x\in X$, then if $x_0 = 0$, we must have $L = 0$, and otherwise

$$\frac{\lVert x_0\rVert_X^2}{2} - L(x_0) \leqslant -\frac{1}{2} L\left(\frac{x_0}{\lVert x_0\rVert_X}\right)^2 \iff \left(L(x_0) - \lVert x_0\rVert_X^2\right)^2\leqslant 0,$$

so $L(x_0) = \lVert x_0\rVert_X^2$, whence $\lVert L\rVert_{X'} \geqslant \lVert x_0\rVert_X$. Furthermore we must then have

$$\lVert L\rVert_{X'}^2 = \sup_{\lVert\xi\rVert_X = 1} L(\xi)^2 \leqslant 2L(x_0) - \lVert x_0\rVert_X^2 = \lVert x_0\rVert^2,$$

and that means $\lVert L\rVert_{X'} \leqslant \lVert x_0\rVert_X$.

A completeness assumption for $X$ is not needed at any step. Furthermore, the above shows that $(1)$ holds for all $x\in X$ if and only if $\lVert L\rVert_{X'} = \lVert x_0\rVert_X$ and $L(x_0) = \lVert x_0\rVert_X^2$, and by the Hahn-Banach theorem(s), there is such an $L\in X'$ for every $x_0 \in X$.

Comment: this is a very elegant proof! Thank you! :)

Comment: sorry for the dumb question, but could you please expand on this $\sup L(\xi) \le 2L(x_0) - \|x_0\|^2$ ?

Comment: Ok, now I can prove it in another way, but I am still interested in how you proved it! :)

Comment: For every $\xi$ with norm $1$, we must have $$\frac{\lVert x_0\rVert_X^2}{2} - L(x_0) \leqslant -\frac{1}{2}L(\xi)^2 = h_\xi(L(\xi)).$$ Multiply that with $-2$ and you get $$L(\xi)^2 \leqslant 2L(x_0) - \lVert x_0\rVert_X^2.$$ Then take the supremum of the left hand side.